# Add object to string in PHP

Tags: php, syntax

I am a bit confused about how to add an object to a string.

I am trying to add the `$this->getUserId();` (which contains the userId of the user).

```
$fileName = "user_.$this->getUserId()".".$fileExt";
```

Comment: Read about [string concatenation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) - there is nothing special with an object (or its method)

Comment: `$fileName = "user_".$this->getUserId().$fileExt;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
$fileName = "user_{$this->getUserId()}.$fileExt";
```

It should give you:

```
user_1.ext
```

See the PHP manual on [strings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php), more specifically the part about [curly braces and 'complex' parsing](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex).

For normal variables you can place them in double quoted strings and they will be parsed. For more complex things like expressions you need to wrap them in `{}` so that they will be parsed.

Comment: hey jd182. thank u so much. i was always confused about that; you have now cleared it up for me

Answer (score 1):

```
$fileName = 'user_'.$this->getUserId().'.'.$fileExt;
```

Comment: No pro;) Don't forget, that string concatanation is . (dot) and usual string is '.' (string with quotes).

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate the object in string using dot (.) operator

$fileName = "user_".$this->getUserId().".".$fileExt";

For more info about PHP string concatenation. You can check the PHP documentation.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php